# Firebase backed UI freezes during cronjob because of 1000 "on" events

Tags: javascript, performance, firebase, event-handling, firebase-realtime-database

I have ReactJs app with Firebase as database/backend.

There are 1000 items that are synced with firebase and i get new data with

```
firebase.database().ref().child('path').on('value', snapshot => {...})
```

while normal usage, users are changing data of that list, it all updates for all and all happy. ReactJs side is optimised well, it all works w/o lag.

Problem if when i run cronjob updating all those items with some 3rd party data and every user get's `on` event fired by firebase 1000 times at once one after the other. Browser freezes, RAM usage ~2-3GB (normal usage ~200mb).

There are 2 options what i'm thinking about, maybe you could add something:

1. Make cron update step-by-step update 1 item per second so fire all those 1000 `on` events during all 15 minutes timespan and just run cron forever, when it's done updating last item, just start again.
2. Make some abstraction layer for firebase connection and if `on` event is fired like 5 times /s disconnect with `off` and then after couple seconds re-connect with `on` so i would be disconnected during batch updates.

I like #2 more because then i can do whatever needed with cronjob and it also solves any possible future issues with batch updates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know, that for most cases it would be possible to limit results with `limitToFirst()` as Frank van Puffelen suggested, but problem is I need all data available in UI for all kind of selections, auto completions not talking about fast data filtering w/o extra call to server

**Current solution:**

I listen for all coming events from firebase if buffer overloads i just use `goOffline` and then re-connect after some time. Client don't see any difference, because `goOffline` lets fire local events normally and all UI works well read more here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Database#goOffline

I add event listener for each child in firebase, i'd like to have one global listener, but it doesn't work for me, there is connected question: [How to listen for ALL firebase .on('value') events on root node?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38368328/how-to-listen-for-all-firebase-onvalue-events-on-root-node)

```
let database = window.firebase.database();

// go offline if incomes more events per second from firebase

let events_buffer = 0;
let online = true;

const go_online = () => {
  if (events_buffer > 6) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      go_online();
    }, 3000);
  } else {
    online = true;
    database.goOnline();
  }
};

const handle_buffer = () => {
  if (events_buffer > 6) {
    if (online) {
      online = false;
      database.goOffline();
      setTimeout(() => {
        go_online();
      }, 5000);
    }
  }
};

setInterval(() => {
  events_buffer = events_buffer > 0 ? events_buffer - 1 : events_buffer;
}, 500);

// listen for all events. Connected: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38368328/how-to-listen-for-all-firebase-onvalue-events-on-root-node

database.ref().child('clients').on('value', () => {
  events_buffer++;
  handle_buffer();
});
database.ref().child('users').on('value', () => {
  events_buffer++;
  handle_buffer();
});

//
// ... add listeners for all childs
//

export const firebase = window.firebase;
```

https://gist.github.com/liesislukas/0d78b6ac9613b70bafbb8e1601cc740e

for max buffer value i use 6 because on initial load app requires ~3-4. 6 can be reached on with some anomaly with my app.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your browser process is getting overloaded by the number of items that are queued up by the batch processing.

The best solution is probably to limit the amount of data that the browser process pulls in from Firebase to something it can handle:

```
firebase.database().ref().child('path')
    .limitToFirst(10)
    .on('child_added', snapshot => {...})
```

This way your browser will never see more than 10 items.

You'll note that I switched from a `value` event to `child_added`, which will probably also help. If you have a queue, you should probably also handle `child_removed` to remove the item from the browser UI. So you'll end up with something like:

```
var query = firebase.database().ref().child('path').limitToFirst(10)
query.on('child_added', snapshot => {
  // add item to UI
})
query.on('child_removed', snapshot => {
  // remove item from UI
})
```